# How to calculate the sum of a column SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Need some help.

My Table is like below->

| Project_Name | Date | Recorded_Hours | Planned_Hours | Remaining_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Civil | 06-03-2022 | 5 | 10 | 5 |
| Civil | 07-03-2022 | 3 | 7 | 4 |
| Civil | 08-03-2022 | 9 | 9 | 0 |
| Civil | 09-03-2022 | 4 | 10 | 6 |
| Civil | 10-03-2022 | 8 | 5 | -3 |
| Civil | 11-03-2022 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| Civil | 12-03-2022 | 0 | 5 | -5 |
| Civil | 13-03-2022 | 0 | 4 | -4 |
| Civil | 14-03-2022 | 0 | 3 | -3 |
| Civil | 15-03-2022 | 0 | 4 | -4 |
| Civil | 15-03-2022 | 0 | 5 | -5 |

Here I have only one project but in real time I have multiple projects.

> In this table **Recorded_Hours** is total hours done per day, **Planned_Hours** is total hours planned per day and **Remaining_Hours** is ( **Planned_Hours** - **Recorded_Hours** ). I want to sum all the **Remaining_Hours** till today then distribute that sum evenly to each future  **Planned_Hours**.
>
> > In this above table total sum of **Remaining_Hours** till today is **12** and there is **5 Days** left to complete this project. I want to add **12/5** to each **5 Days** left **Planned_Hours**. This should automatically calculate everyday.

My output will be ->

| Project_Name | Date | Recorded_Hours | Planned_Hours | Remaining_Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Civil | 06-03-2022 | 5 | 10 | 5 |
| Civil | 07-03-2022 | 3 | 7 | 4 |
| Civil | 08-03-2022 | 9 | 9 | 0 |
| Civil | 09-03-2022 | 4 | 10 | 6 |
| Civil | 10-03-2022 | 8 | 5 | -3 |
| Civil | 11-03-2022 | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| Civil | 12-03-2022 | 0 | 7.4 | -7.4 |
| Civil | 13-03-2022 | 0 | 6.4 | -6.4 |
| Civil | 14-03-2022 | 0 | 5.4 | -5.4 |
| Civil | 15-03-2022 | 0 | 6.4 | -6.4 |
| Civil | 15-03-2022 | 0 | 7.4 | -7.4 |

Till now I have reached to this point

```
SELECT 
 [Project_Name]= CASE WHEN GROUPING(Date) = 0 THEN [Project_Name]ELSE 'Total' END,
  Date,
  [Remaining_Hours] = SUM([Planned_Hours]-[Recorded_Hours])
FROM[dbo].[Projects]

GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    ([Project_Name], Date),
    ([Project_Name]));
```

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried ?

Comment: Hi, @Squirrel I am new to SQL. Till now I am using Grouping Set to calculate sum of each project individually. But now I don't know where to go.

Comment: Are you related to the OP of [this identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71407637/how-to-distribute-total-sum-of-a-column-to-another-columns-data-evenly-in-sql)  ?

Comment: @Squirrel I don't know which question you are talking but the question you have attached is removed I guess.

Comment: That question is identical as yours and it was deleted by OP

Comment: anyway, StackOverflow is not a free code writing services. Please show us your best attempt. Split the problem into sections. Attempt to solve one by one. Example, first you need to find total remaining hours up till today. After that find no of future days left. Divice total remaining hours by the days you will get the incremental days required to add to the balance future dates

Comment: @Squirrel Till Now I have reached to this point SELECT 
 [Project_Name]= CASE WHEN GROUPING(Date) = 0 THEN [Project_Name]ELSE 'Total' END,
  Date,
  [Remaining_Hours] = SUM([Planned_Hours]-[Recorded_Hours])
FROM  .[dbo].[Projects_DataSet]
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    ([Project_Name], Date),
    ([Project_Name]));

Comment: Please edit the question and include the query. It is very hard to read in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you find Total Remaining Hours up to today for each project (GROUP BY)

```
select Project, Total_Remaining_Hours = sum(Remaining_Hours),
from   Projects
where  [Date] <= @today 
group by Project
```

Then you also required no of remaining days

```
select Project, Remaining_Days = count(*)
from   Projects
where  [Date] > @today 
group by Project
```

Combining it all together (INNER JOIN) and use `CASE` expression to check, ignore past date and only adjust the future dates

```
declare @today date = getdate();

select *,
       New_Planned_Hours = case when p.[Date] <= @today
                                then p.Planned_Hours
                                else p.Planned_Hours 
                                +    (t.Total_Remaining_Hours / d.Remaining_Days)
                                end
from   Projects p
       inner join
       (
          select Project,
                 Total_Remaining_Hours = sum(Remaining_Hours)
          from   Projects
          where  [Date] <= @today
          group by Project
       ) t  on p.Project = t.Project
       inner join
       (
          select Project,
                 Remaining_Days = count(*)
          from   Projects
          where  [Date] > @today
          group by Project
       ) d  on p.Project = d.Project
order by p.Project, p.[Date]
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45d338b5a5a6e02d4e5586c18ebbb007)